# Finding a variable in a python list

Tags: python

im trying to search for a variable in a list that’s returned by a function

```
        hid = '282'
if __name__ == '__main__':


    filename = "foo.txt"

    z = get_history_ids2(sid)
    with open(filename) as f:
        data = f.readlines()

    for r in z: 
        if int('4216') in data is False:
            print 'lose'
        else:
            print 'win'
    print data


    print (hid)
    print z
```

im getting false... or in other words it does not see number "282" although it does exist in the list

> [281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 294, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 312, 313, 314, 318, 319, 320, 321, 322, 323, 414, 415, 416, 417, 418]

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I can't run your code, so wild guess: try replacing your first line with `hid = 282`

Comment: `'282'` is a string, and not equal to the number `282`. Maybe that's what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

Your program is correctly reporting that the string '282' is not in the list. You could find the int 282 in that same list:

```
In [1]: x = [281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 294, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 312, 313, 314, 318, 319, 320, 321, 322, 323, 414, 415, 416, 417, 418]

In [2]: '282' in x
Out[2]: False

In [3]: 282 in x
Out[3]: True

In [4]: int('282') in x
Out[4]: True
```

Comment: how would i fix that? the "hid" variable will change everytime

Comment: i just changed the code up top , im new to stack exvhange also

Comment: Hard to say from what you have here. In general, you need to go looking for the right thing (int, string, etc.) in the list. If you start with a string but are looking for an int (or vice-versa) you'll need to convert it.

Comment: how do i know what i should type it as?